# Dois programas iguais fornecendo saídas diferentes

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou desenvolvendo um programa que é um daqueles exercícios clássicos de programação que envolvem a sequência de Fibonacci. O programa é simples, ele pede que o usuário informe um termo da sequência e o programa diz qual o número da sequência ocupa aquele termo. Exemplo: O 5º termo da sequência é 5, o 10º termo é 55 e por aí vai.

Desenvolvi para isso o seguinte código:

```
n = int(input("Digite o termo da sequência Fibonacci: "))
a = 1
b = 1
k = 1
while k <= n - 2:
    a = b
    b = a + b
    k = k + 1
print("O {}º da Sequência de Fibonacci é ocupado pelo número {}.".format(n,b))
```

Entretanto, quando executo o programa, o mesmo não funciona como o esperado. Vejam:

> ```
> Digite o termo da sequência Fibonacci: 5
> O 5º da Sequência de Fibonacci é ocupado pelo número 8.
> ```

De novo:

> ```
> Digite o termo da sequência Fibonacci: 10
> O 10º da Sequência de Fibonacci é ocupado pelo número 256.
> ```

Busquei soluções na internet para ver onde estava errando e encontrei no curso Python para Zumbis uma solução que resolve o problema corretamente:

```
n = int(input("Digite o termo da sequência Fibonacci: "))
a, b = 1, 1
k = 1
while k <= n - 2:
    a, b = b, a + b
    k = k + 1
print("O {}º da Sequência de Fibonacci é ocupado pelo número {}.".format(n,b))
```

Observem as saídas:

> ```
> Digite o termo da sequência Fibonacci: 5
> O 5º da Sequência de Fibonacci é ocupado pelo número 5.
> ```

De novo:

> ```
> Digite o termo da sequência Fibonacci: 10
> O 10º da Sequência de Fibonacci é ocupado pelo número 55.
> ```

Como podem ver, as duas últimas saídas estão corretas.

O grande problema é que, pelo menos ao meu ver, os códigos são exatamente iguais, a diferença é que um ocupa menos linhas que o outro, ou estou errado? Por que as saídas são diferentes?

Comment: A ordem que as coisas acontecem ...
`a, b = b, a + b`

é equivalente a 
`b = a+b` e depois 
`a = b`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Porque os códigos não são iguais, são bem diferentes.

No seu código você está somando `a` com `b`, só que pouco antes você disse que `a` é o mesmo valor de `b`, então na prática você está sempre somando `b`, com `b`. Para isto dar certo você teria que mudar o valor de `a` depois de fazer a soma, mas para isto funcionar teria que criar uma variável temporária, você não pode mudar o valor de `b` antes de fazer mudança. Veja:

```
a, b = b, a + b
```

Ao mesmo tempo você está dizendo que `a` passar ser igual a `b`, e `b` é igual `a + b` sendo que o valor de `a` aí ainda não foi modificado. Ele permite uma operação de *swap* sem armazenamento temporário.

No código que você pegou ele faz uma atribuição como tuplas, ou seja, ele faz as operações de forma concomitante, então quando você faz `a + b` o valor de `a` é o valor original, a mudança de valor de `a` para `b` ainda não ocorreu, então tudo dá certo.

Este recurso de Python é uma beleza porque causa disto, não precisa de uma variável temporária, e é a forma idiomática da linguagem, prefira fazer assim.

Seu código funcionaria assim:

```
n = int(input("Digite o termo da sequência Fibonacci: "))
a = 1
b = 1
k = 1
while k <= n - 2:
    tmp = a
    a = b
    b = tmp + b
    k = k + 1
print("O {}º da Sequência de Fibonacci é ocupado pelo número {}.".format(n,b))
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/tNXntH). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ckvhmhyf-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/Fibonacci.py).

Comment: Então quando eu escrevo na mesma linha ou em linhas diferentes faz diferença?

Comment: Sim, a linguagem é uma sequência de comandos, a ordem deles faz diferença, a não ser nos casos que seja igual mesmo. Não precisa ser só mudar de linha, basta mudar a ordem na mesma linha. Se você mudar a ordem de uma soma ou multiplicação não muda nada, mas se mudar a ordem em uma subtração ou divisão muda completamente o resultado. Neste caso colocar em linhas separadas faz o que eu expliquei.

Answer (score 4):

Os programas não são iguais.

Quando você fez

```
a = b
```

você acabou de perder o valor original de `a`.

Seu programa deveria contornar esse problema da seguinte forma,

```
temp = a
a = b
b = temp + b
k = k + 1
```

Comment: Não entendi porquê ele deveria contornar o problema com uma variável temporária se ele já contornou da forma idiomática que é fazendo a desconstrução de tuplas: `a, b = b, a+b`.

Answer (score 4):

O problema é que as expressões...

`a, b = b, a + b`

e

```
a = b
b = a + b
```

...não são iguais e tampouco apresentam o mesmo resultado.

Na primeira expressão o valor de `a` no lado direito da expressão(após o `=`) ainda não sofreu a alteração pretendida. Portanto a operação `a, b = b, a + b` equivale a:

```
t = a      # o valor de 'a' é armazenado em uma variável temporária.
a = b 
b = t + b  # aqui 'b' recebe 'b' mais o antigo valor de 'a'
```